# Browse Files From the "My Computer "path

Tags: java, swt

I need to Browse the File from the path i.e "MY computer". I don't specify the drive as 'c' or 'd'.

The path should point to "My Computer" by default.

Can any open helps me.

We are Using SWT.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.open();
DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell);
dialog.setFilterPath(" "); //MyComputer
System.out.println("RESULT=" + dialog.open());
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work on Windows, so if you're planning to release your software for other OSs, then you'll have to find alternatives for those.

Comment: Is there any alternative which helps me??

Comment: @AnushaVinod Would instead using the user's home directory meet your needs? There is a `user.home` [system property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to get that location easily.

Answer (score 0):

Following will select the `My Computer` entry by default.

```
dialog.setFilterPath("::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}");
```